# Can you get the return value of a thread if it exited before you call join?

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join, pthread-exit

If you have a thread A which calls `pthread_exit(return_val)` before thread B can call
`pthread_join(A, ret_val_A)`, what is the outcome? Does join return as if the thread did not exist?

Clarification: Im not asking if you can join once a thread has exited, more so will the return value be valid if it has already exited and you call join after.

Comment: 1. Why don't you read the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)? 2. Why don't you write some code and try it?

Comment: i did, it does not specify. obviously some systems are different than others so I was wondering if it was generally considered unsafe.